# how to Get Windows Username in WPF

Tags: wpf

I would like to display the Username in my WPF application, where it should get the username from the current user logged in?

so my question how can we get the username of windows logged in user from WPF App ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

I also found:

```
Environment.UserName
```

or

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName
```

I cannot try it so check for yourself the result.

Added:
Full user name:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Dim userFullName As String = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, This one is working Thank you

Comment: How can i get the Complete user name instead of Just User ID  Example : instead of Displaying Ujjwal27 display "Ujjwal Vaddepati"

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName is also useful - and necessary for providing the meaningful hint in ADAL.

Answer (score 12):

Call `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to get the Windows user identity.

You can get the name from this.