# How can i get the Complete user name in Windows 7 using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried this link, but i am getting only the user id i want the complete name of the user

[Username in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273659/how-to-get-windows-username-in-wpf/16273715?noredirect=1#16273715)

Comment: Where are you expecting the user name to come from? Is it in the database, and are you retrieving it when the user logs in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175004/get-windows-user-name-different-methods

Comment: i am trying to get it in my WPF application , the present logged in user name from windows machine(complete user name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the full name of the user logged in on the computer

```
Thread.GetDomain().SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsPrincipal principal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
// or, if you're in Asp.Net with windows authentication you can use:
// WindowsPrincipal principal = (WindowsPrincipal)User;
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, principal.Identity.Name);
    thisUsername = up.DisplayName;
    // or return up.GivenName + " " + up.Surname;
}
```